# Find an Euler path

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, eulerian-path

I don't have an answer for this exercise, so I'm asking you.

Exercise: Draw a graph with 6 vertices with the degrees: 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4. Name the vertices a, b, c, d, e, f (in the order you want), and then find an Euler path in your graph. My solution :
[image]

Comment: I find your answer quite correct.

Comment: Looks good, good job!

Answer (score 1):

It looks correct.  Here's a drawing where I've added edge directions and increasingly blue colors according to the Eulerian path, and identified the vertex degrees (ignoring edge directions).

[image]